# Xml Sitemaps for large websites

Tags: xml, web, sitemap

How do large websites deal with thousands of old urls that are deleted everyday? particularly when the website redirects to a customized error page on hitting a broken url instead of throwing a 404 error page. (I've read search engine crawlers do not consider urls that throw 404 error page)

Answer (score 1):

If a page is deleted, I'd strongly recommend that you make your "customized error page" actually return a "410 Gone" HTTP header.

Comment: If it has been *deleted* that should be `410 Gone` rather then `404 Not Found`